# can execute php file from browser but cron job get fatal error on shared server hostgator

Tags: php, curl, cron, host

I can execute my php scrape file by typing in the address bar:

```
domain.com/scrape.php
```

However, I try to use cron job on my shared server on host gator by this command:

```
/usr/bin/php-cli public_html/scrape.php
```

I got this error message:
Fatal error: `Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Handler\curl_reset() in /home4/username/public_html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 78`
I already update my php version to stable 5.6 or even 5.7  version also same error. I think that it should not be php version error because I still can execute the file from browser right ?
Also I cannot reboot server Apache because hostgator support said they cannot reboot it until the server is totally down...
Any help please ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem last week on my own server.  As it turned out, my browser was looking at one installation of PHP and cron was looking at a 2nd installation of PHP.  One way to check is to run a PHP script through your browser that executes phpinfo().  That will tell you what the browser is running.  Have cron do the same and save the results.  Compare the two and make sure they're pointing to the same installation of PHP.  Don't just check versions.  Check install paths and loaded modules.  Cheers.

Comment: How do I check cron using what version ? and browser is client site only, if it call php file on server, it must run php on server and it should be same as cron use right?

Comment: I will ssh to my server and use command line from there, which commands should I type to check version of php used for browser and which used for cron ?

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I find out here is the way to force cron to use which version of php (version5.6): /opt/php56/bin/php instead of /usr/bin/php-cli above. Will accept your solution! Thank you.

Comment: similarly, when I run: "composer update" it also take the wrong (older) php version (php 5.4.45), so I fix it by: "/opt/php56/bin/php composer.phar update"